# Transform a Flowable of Single's<User> into a Flowable of List<User>

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have this Rx Stream that was used to group a list of UserScoreTO into a single User object (many-to-one relation).

```
public void execute() {
    getUsers()
            .flatMap(list -> Flowable.fromIterable(list))
            .groupBy(userScoreTO -> userScoreTO.id)
            .flatMap(groups -> Flowable.fromCallable(() -> groups.collect(User::new, (user, userscore) -> {
                user.id = userscore.id;
                user.name = userscore.name;
                user.totalScore += userscore.score;
            }))).subscribe(userSingle -> userSingle.subscribe(new SingleObserver<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            System.out.println("onSubscribe");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(User user) {
            System.out.println(user);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }
    }));

}
```

As you can see, to consume this flowable I subscribed to it, consuming some `Single's`  that it emits. So I subscribe to that single's too. Although this even works, it's a bit annoying... I would like to make only one subscription and to consume a collection of users...

A few days ago I asked another question [about this same code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380787/how-to-merge-several-objects-into-a-single-one-after-execute-the-groupby-operati). the full code of that class is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting a `flatMap` at the end removes the need for that nested `subscribe`.

Example:

```
getUsers()
    .flatMap(list -> Flowable.fromIterable(list))
    .groupBy(userScoreTO -> userScoreTO.id)
    .flatMap(groups -> 
        Flowable.fromCallable(() -> 
            groups.collect(User::new, (user, userscore) -> {
                user.id = userscore.id;
                user.name = userscore.name;
                user.totalScore += userscore.score;
            }
    )))
    .flatMap(it -> it.toFlowable()) // <-- unwrap the singles
    .subscribe(user -> System.out.println(user));
```

Comment: that's what I needed!

Comment: wait.. I needed an user list...  but I did .toList().subscribe(list -> list.forEach(System.out::println)) and that's it...

Comment: Note even that - there's a `.flatMapSingle` that does exactly this and is faster.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos oh, I didn't know about that one, thanks! Then, in case of using `flatMapSingle` it would then be written as `.flatMapSingle(it -> it)`.